# How can i use dynamically generated string inside `list() = $variable`?

Tags: php

I am trying to dynamically generate a string n then use it inside `list()` to catch array values in variables.

Code :

```
<?php

$bubba = "value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7";

$hubba = explode(",", $bubba);

$num = count($hubba);

ob_start();

for($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++){

    echo ('$k'.$i.', ');

}

$varname = ob_get_clean();

$varname = substr($varname, 0, -2);

list(echo $varname;) = $hubba;
```

I want this to look like:

```
list($k1, $k2, $k3, $k4, $k5, $k6, $k7) = $hubba;

echo $k1; // must echo value1

?>
```

But, list simply is not-ready to accept the variable string. How to do this ?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, this is the wrong way.

Comment: If you remove "echo" and the smiley from the `list()` call you might get better results.

Comment: you mean : list($varname) ?? I tried this, but list isnt accepting this

Comment: @AbraCadaver Then how can i extract individual value from string n use them individually ? Yes, it can be done with code : foreach($hubba as $k=>$v){} , but without this ??

Comment: You need to show what you have which is `"value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7"` and what do you want it to look like or how do you need to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve a problem the wrong way.  Most experienced developers will tell you that they have been down this road and it's a dead end.  Why use `$k0` instead of the existing `$k[0]`?  However, for fun, here is a working example:

```
extract($hubba, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'k');
echo $k_0;
```

Or another, for fun, that does it the way you describe:

```
foreach($hubba as $k => $v) {
    ${'k'.($k+1)} = $v;
}
echo $k1;
```

Or finally, for more fun, using `list()` for no apparent reason:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
    $var[] = '$k'.$i;
}
$vars = implode(', ', $var);

eval("list($vars) = \$hubba;");

echo $k1;
```

I would encourage you to include **WHY** you think you need this and there is definitely a better solution.

Comment: Thanks mate. I knew this 2nd solution, but, i just happnd to go that way n found that its not working. Then i wanted to know the reason, that why list() isnt accepting that. Thanks anyways ! :)

Comment: This isn't really what list is for, but added more fun.

Comment: @luna.romania, one better way to say thanks is accepting the answer :)